# how to remove an event listener in vue 3 correctly

Tags: vue.js, event-listener, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, removeeventlistener

I have an event listener that gets the viewport dimensions when the project is mounted and after each resize event.

I don't know how to remove the event listener correctly.

```js
const { createApp, onMounted, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const dim = ref({})
    
    onMounted(() => {
      dim.value = getDimensions()
      // adding the event listener...
      window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => {
        // ...but how to remove the event listener correctly?
        console.log('resize')
        dim.value = getDimensions()
      }, 250))
    })
    
    function getDimensions () {
      return {
        w: window.innerWidth,
        h: window.innerHeight
      }
    }
    
    // generic debounce function
    function debounce (func, wait) {
    let timeout
    return function executedFunction (...args) {
      const later = () => {
      timeout = null
          func(...args)
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
      }
    }

    return {
      dim
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #555;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="navbar">
    <p>
      <span>width: {{ dim.w + ' ' }}</span>
      <span>| height: {{ dim.h }}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would you remove the event listener?

I am using Vue 3 with the composition API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

why not in a `unmounted` life cycle hook ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram))

```js
window.removeEventListener("resize", debounce);
```

For Vue 3 Composition API the respective hook is `onUnmounted` (see the [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onunmounted))

Comment: Make sure to pass the result of `debounce()` (the same instance passed to `addEventListener`), not `debounce` itself.

Comment: @tony19 - is this a note in general or should I change something?

Comment: Yes, a change is needed. Cache the result of `debounce`, pass that to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use VueUse [useEventListener](https://vueuse.org/core/useeventlistener/) which automatically removes the listener on unmount.

Example from the docs:

```js
import { useEventListener } from '@vueuse/core'

const element = ref<HTMLDivElement>()
useEventListener(element, 'keydown', (e) => {
  console.log(e.key)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually define my event method outside of mounted

```
onResize() {
    debounce(() => {
        // ...but how to remove the event listener correctly?
        console.log('resize')
        dim.value = getDimensions()
      }, 250))
    })
}
```

then inside of mounted you can use

```
onMounted(() => {
  dim.value = getDimensions()
  // adding the event listener...
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
})
```

and inside of beforeUnmount

```
beforeUnmount(() => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
})
```

Comment: he is using vue3, they changed the hooks

Answer (score 2):

In `vue 3 script setup` it works like this.

```
<script setup>
import {onMounted, onUnmounted} from "vue";


function yourFunction(event) {
    //do something
}

onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', yourFunction)
})

onUnmounted(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('click', yourFunction);
})
</script>
```

If you figure out how to remove event listeners from `anonymous functions`, let me know.